# Can't get div to have background-color

Tags: html, background-color

I have the following html markup:

```
            <div id="com_loaded">
                <div id="com_loaded_userpic"><a href="#" class="tooltip"><img src="pic.jpg" class="img_poster" /><span>Username</span></a></div>
                <div id="com_loaded_content">
                    <div id="com_loaded_poster">Username</a></div>
                    <div id="com_loaded_text">Comment text</div>
                </div> 
            </div>
```

and the following css markup:

```
 #com_loaded {
position: relative;
width: 250px;
padding: 0px;
clear: both;
background-color:#3FC;
 }

 #com_loaded_userpic {
position: relative;
width: 55px;
height: 60px;
float: left;
padding-left: 5px;
 }

 #com_loaded_content {
position: relative;
width: 185px;
float: left;
padding-left: 5px;
 }

 #com_loaded_poster {
position: relative;
width: 185px;
float: left;
clear: left;    
 }

 #com_loaded_text {
position: relative;
width: 185px;
float: left;
clear: left;
padding-bottom: 10px;
 }
```

The container, com_loaded, has a background-color. But this background color isn't showed. When I give a height to the container, it is showed. But as the comment_text doesn't have a certain height (it depends how long the comment is), I don't wanna set a height.

How can I show the background-color of the container for all the divs in the container? I don't know what I'm doing wrong....

Comment: I don't want to have an scrollbar in a single comment.... but your solution shows the background color, but my layout is changed then....

Comment: have you tested it? Do you see a scrollbar?

Comment: yes I've tested it, it doesn't show a scrollbar. But my float: left with clear: left layout is messed up then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The floating contents do not affect the layout of their container, so any item wrapped around a floating div will have no height unless you explicitly set it (or unless there are other elements that would give it a height). You can correct this by adding a `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` at the end of #com-loaded.

Comment: Jason, that's a great explanation! it works perfectly. I didn't know about the floating contents getting no height without the clear:both div. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Stefan You're very welcome! I'm glad my explanation was clear.